# React-native-navigation: how to start the playground app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I cloned into the react-native-navigation git and would like to use their showcase app. However, running `npm run install-android` and then `npm run start` does not start the app. When I use the `npm run test-unit-android` the test work.

What am I doing wrong or seeing?

Comment: I would try asking by opening an issue in their Github's repo...

Comment: What you mean with 'does not start the app'? what is the error or message?